# Vertically aligning multiple v-slide-group in Vuetify

Tags: javascript, html, css, vuejs2, vuetify.js

I have more than 1 v-slide-group that the user is seeing.

Some of those v-slide-group will overflow and have arrow showing, and some won't.

However, since the arrow will only begin to take up space when the arrow is showing, it'll lead to a misalignment with the v-slide-group that won't have any overflows.

The question is, how can I best align the multiple v-slide-groups?

P.S. I'm attaching pictures below as reference

[image: A misaligned v-slide-group]

What happens when one group overflows and the other didn't

[image: Forced to always show arrows]

I could always force to show the arrows, but I'd like the arrows to only be shown if it does overflow

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to use slots to provide the content you want to show. For example:

```
<template v-slot:prev>
  ... perhaps an icon ...
</template>
<template v-slot:next>
  ... perhaps an icon ...
</template>
```

And then show or hide the content of the slot based on some overflow indicator that you provide.